# Check string for "tag" phrases in SQL Server table using Classic ASP

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing a search system...

A user enters the following search: "project managers finance"

We have a table with tags...

`tbl_tags` with the following items (phrases) in the table:

```
ID   Tag
 1   Project Managers
 2   Programme Managers
 3   Finance
 4   Finance Managers
```

I want to split the search phrase and pull results that have only are exactly matched in the database. E.g. ID's 1 and 3 (not 2 and 4)

What is the best way to go about this as a SQL query?

My current method is very long winded and involves producing all results for each word in the query e.g. `Contains(tag,"project OR manager OR finance")`, producing all results for that then comparing each produced `tag` using `instr(query,oRS("Tag"))`.

I have full text enabled so can use `contains` if necessary.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Enterprise Manager (Db is SQL Server 2008 R2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found a solution for this problem, using `CHARINDEX` to compare the `CONTAINS` results to a string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A by-the-book implementation:

```vb
Option Explicit

Const adVarChar = 200  ' remove if that constant is already defined

Dim tags, term
Dim placeholders, sql, cmd, result

tags = Split(Request("searchterms"), " ")

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = dbConnection ' I assume the connection object exists

For Each term In tags    
  term = Trim(term)
  If term <> "" Then 
    placeholders = placeholders & ",?"    
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(, adVarChar, , 100, term)
  End If
Next

If cmd.Parameters.Count > 0 Then
  sql = "SELECT id FROM tbl_tags WHERE tag IN (" & Mid(placeholders, 2) & ")" 
  cmd.CommandText = sql

  Set result = cmd.execute

  While Not result.EOF
    Response.Write result.Fields("id") ' whatever
    result.MoveNext
  Wend
End If
```

Also have a look into the [documentation of `CreateParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).